# Why won't the prgram execute the switch?

Tags: c, encryption

This a simple cipher code. I do not really understand why the switch statement won't execute. Everything before the switch statement works. If you could briefly explain how to fix this, that would be great. I recently started coding in C so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question! Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char letter;    
    char word[100];

    int i;
    int j; 
    int x;

    int shift;
    int stringLength;

    printf("Enter d to DECRYPT.\n");
    printf("Enter e to ENCRYPT.\n");

    scanf("%c", & letter);

    if(letter == 'd' || letter == 'D') // d = 0, e = 1
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    else if(letter == 'e' || letter == 'E')
    {
        x = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The letter you entered was neither d or e!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("\nEnter the number of shifts:\n");
    scanf("%d", &shift);

    printf("\nEnter the word or phrase you would like to Encrypt or Decrpyt\n");
    scanf("%s", word);
    //printf("\nThe word you entered was:\n%s\n", word);

    stringLength = strlen(word);
    //printf("\nThe size of the string is: %i\n", stringLength);

    switch(x)
    {
        case 0:     // decrypt

            for(i = 0; (i < 100 && word[i] != '\0'); i++)
                word[i] = word[i] - shift;

            break;

            /*
             *    while(i < stringLength)
             *    {
             *        word[i] = word[i] - shift;
             *        i++;
             *        
             *        printf("The Decrypted word is: %s\n", word);
             */
            //break;

        case 1: // encrypt

            for(i = 0; (i < 100 && word[i] != '\0'); i++)
                word[i] = word[i] + shift;

            break;


            /*
             * while( i < stringLength)
             * {
             *    word[i] = word[i] + shift;
             *    i++;
             * 
             *    printf("The Encrypted word is: %s\n", word);
             */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi sergio, and welcome to Stack Overflow! What exactly do you mean when you say "the switch statement won't execute"? Presumably your code compiles, but does it run without giving an error? What happens when you run it, and specifically what does it do that tells you the switch statement isn't executing? What do you expect to see it do instead? Also, while it's great that you included sample code, it would be even better if you could simplify it down to [a very short, simple program that reproduces your problem and does little else](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I recommend you read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); if you have a problem with only the switch statement then you are more likely to get help if you can reduce the problem to the minimal example necessary to reproduce it. This example is 84 lines with multiple blocks of code commented out.

Comment: What makes you sure that the `switch` is not entered? It could also be the case that it is entered but does not yield any countable/observable changes.

Comment: @DavidZ Thank you for responding so fast! So the code does compile without giving me any errors. What the switch statement is supposed to do is depending on whether the user entered 'd' or 'e', it would either subtract or add however many shifts to the word entered. For example, If the shift number was 2, the letter 'c' would become the letter 'a' if the user chose to decrypt or it would become the letter 'e' if the user chose to encrypt.

Comment: Your code was doing the intended thing. Its just that you had not printed to value to see what was happening. Please see my answer which resolves your query.@sergio

Answer (score 1):

Your `switch` was being *executed*, but the body of each `case` had too many commented out parts.

Use `fgets` instead of `scanf` for the phrase as `scanf` will only get the *first* word.

*Side note:* I'd use `#if 0` and `#endif` instead of `/*` and `*/` to comment out blocks of code.

Note that although you *can* intermix `scanf` and `fgets`, I've recoded to use just `fgets` and `strtol`.

Here is the cleaned up and working code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char word[100];

void
get(void)
{

    fgets(word,sizeof(word),stdin);
    char *cp = strchr(word,'\n');
    if (cp != NULL)
        *cp = 0;

}

int
main()
{

    char letter;

    int i;
    int j;
    int x;

    int shift;
    int stringLength;

    printf("Enter d to DECRYPT.\n");
    printf("Enter e to ENCRYPT.\n");

    get();
    letter = word[0];

    if (letter == 'd' || letter == 'D') // d = 0, e = 1
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    else if (letter == 'e' || letter == 'E') {
        x = 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("The letter you entered was neither d or e!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("\nEnter the number of shifts:\n");
    get();
    shift = strtol(word,NULL,10);

    printf("\nEnter the word or phrase you would like to Encrypt or Decrpyt\n");
#if 0
    scanf("%s", word);
#else
    get();
#endif
    printf("\nThe word you entered was:\n%s\n", word);

    stringLength = strlen(word);
    printf("\nThe size of the string is: %i\n", stringLength);

    printf("x=%d\n", x);
    switch (x) {
    case 0:                         // decrypt
        printf("decrypt case\n");

        for (i = 0; (i < 100 && word[i] != '\0'); i++)
            word[i] = word[i] - shift;

#if 0
        while (i < stringLength) {
            word[i] = word[i] - shift;
            i++;
        }

#endif
        printf("The Decrypted word is: %s\n", word);
        break;

    case 1:                         // encrypt
        printf("encrypt case\n");
        for (i = 0; (i < 100 && word[i] != '\0'); i++)
            word[i] = word[i] + shift;

#if 0
        while (i < stringLength) {
            word[i] = word[i] + shift;
            i++;
        }
#endif

        printf("The Encrypted word is: %s\n", word);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the word soon after the case is executed. Also, please format the code. Here is the formatted code that works:

```
int main() {
  char letter, word[100];
  int i,j, x, shift, stringLength;

  printf("Enter d to DECRYPT or e to ENCRYPT.\n");
  scanf("%c", &letter);

  if(letter == 'd' || letter == 'D') {
    x = 0;
  } else if(letter == 'e' || letter == 'E') {
    x = 1;
  }
  else {
    printf("The letter you entered was neither d or e!\n");
    return 0;
  }

  printf("\nEnter the number of shifts:\n");
  scanf("%d", &shift);

  printf("\nEnter the word or phrase you would like to Encrypt or Decrpyt\n");
  scanf("%s", word);

  stringLength = strlen(word);

  switch(x) {
    case 0:
      for(i = 0; (i < 100 && word[i] != '\0'); i++) {
        word[i] = word[i] - shift;
      }
      printf("The decrypted word is: %s\n", word);
      break;

    case 1: // encrypt
      for(i = 0; (i < 100 && word[i] != '\0'); i++) {
        word[i] = word[i] + shift;
      }
      printf("The encrypted word is: %s\n", word);
      break;

    default:
      printf("Invalid case where the value of x is %d \n",x);
  }

  return 0;
}
```